# How is Rehoboam Jewish?

Tags: conversion-to-judaism

It is repeatedly stressed in Tanach that Rehoboam's mother was Naamah the Ammonite. The chief god of which was Molech aka Milcom.

We like to say that all of Shlomo's wives converted but wouldn't the flagrant Molech worship going on in the palace indicate that her conversion was nonsense?

Comment: See Rambam Issurei Biah 13:16 https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Forbidden_Intercourse.13.16?lang=bi

Comment: The Gemara Bava Kama 38B says Moshe Rabbeinu was told not to start up with Amon because Naama would one day emerge from that nation. So her conversion must of been sincere at the time, and she changed later on. The Radak send to indicate that as well. https://www.sefaria.org/Radak_on_I_Kings.14.21.1?lang=he

Comment: She was sincere at the time ... but after a few years, she fell back on old habits. I suspect the "wow" factor wore off. Sadly, any rabbi who does conversions will know a case or two like this sooner or later.

Comment: Biblical Judaism was patrilineal, this is why no conversion is ever mentioned in the scriptures IMHO. The matrilineal tradition was Ezrah's decree that stuck, but only for determining Jewishness (not tribes or classes).

Comment: @al berko the Talmud clearly states king Solomon converted his wives. The Givonim converted in the times of Yehoshua. Throughout Tanach there are stories of conversion. The Talmud says Shimshon converted his wife. Are you suggesting that the Talmud just made it up? Do you have any source whatsoever that Ezra was the original initiator of this?

Comment: Where do you see that she was a practicing worshipper of Molech? Ruth is also referred to as a Moabite even though she fully converted?

Comment: Kings I 11:8. And so he did for all of his alien wives who offered incense and slaughtered sacrifices to their deities. It says "all" in Hebrew too.

Comment: It seems evident that the idolatry only took place near the end of Shlomo's life, which is why he was only punished circa that time. Note also that it's quite possible that not all of Shlomo's wives were still alive at the time. There may have been more than one wife who worshiped Milcom.